# Data row need to get value from row

Tags: c#, datarow

I am using select to get integer from database. Need to do comparison on value after for loop. Please could someone help how to compare in the statement.

```
using (SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(acmd))
{
    using (DataTable adt = new DataTable())
    {
        ac.Open();
        acmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ada.Fill(adt);

        foreach (DataRow row in adt.Rows)
        {
            if (**value in DataTable** > local variable)
            {
                enter code here
            }
```

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery does not return a DataTable. It just returns the number of rows affected by your query (which you don't seem to provide either).

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for the comment. Does the query matter? I am retrieving integer values from 1 column in the table and need to compare them with a local variable. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
{
     if (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[j][0])>local variable)
     {
           enter code here
     }
}


dt.Rows[j][0]
j=>Row number
0=>Columns number (SQL Query Order Column)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data that will be in each row element will be aligned to the column names of the db table you are calling from.

So I think the code you would are looking for would be like.

```
foreach (DataRow row in adt.Rows)
    {
        if (row["ColumnNameFromDbTable"] > local variable)
        {
            enter code here
        }
    }
```

Remember that you may need to format the data, to get it into the correct type.